# r data.table : lagging a date variable

Tags: r, data.table

I have data that looks similar to the following except with hundreds of IDs and thousands of observations:

```
ID     date          measles
1      2008-09-12    1
1      2008-10-25    NA
1      2009-01-12    1
1      2009-03-12    NA
1      2009-05-12    1
2      2010-05-17    NA
2      2010-06-12    NA
2      2010-07-02    1
2      2010-08-13    NA
```

I want to create a variable that will store the previous date for each pid like the following:

```
ID     date          measles  previous_date
1      2008-09-12    1        NA
1      2008-10-25    NA       2008-09-12      
1      2009-01-12    1        2008-10-25
1      2009-03-12    NA       2009-01-12
1      2009-05-12    1        2009-03-12 
2      2010-05-17    NA       NA
2      2010-06-12    NA       2010-05-17
2      2010-07-02    1        2010-06-12
2      2010-08-13    NA       2010-07-02
```

This should be an extremely easy task, but I have been unsuccessful at getting a lag variable to work properly. I have tried a few methods, such as the following:

```
dt[, previous_date:=c(NA, current_date[-.N]), by=c("ID")]

dt[,previous_date:=current_date-shift(current_date,1,type="lag"),by=ID]
```

The code samples above either produce sporadic numbers in the previous_date variable or produce all NAs. I'm not sure why this is? Is it because I'm using a date variable as opposed to an integer?

Is there a better way to accomplish this task that would work for a date variable?

Comment: In the second code, why do you need `current_date -`

Comment: @akrun that is a good question. It could just be written wrong. I used the format based off another example I found online.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can just use `shift` on the 'date' column grouped by 'ID'.  By default the `type` is `lag`

```
library(data.table)
dt[, previous_date := shift(date), ID]

dt
#    ID       date measles previous_date
#1:  1 2008-09-12       1          <NA>
#2:  1 2008-10-25      NA    2008-09-12
#3:  1 2009-01-12       1    2008-10-25
#4:  1 2009-03-12      NA    2009-01-12
#5:  1 2009-05-12       1    2009-03-12
#6:  2 2010-05-17      NA          <NA>
#7:  2 2010-06-12      NA    2010-05-17
#8:  2 2010-07-02       1    2010-06-12
#9:  2 2010-08-13      NA    2010-07-02
```